# How can I create a .bashrc file that works on both Linux and OSX

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ubuntu

I find that some functions and programs are available on one system but not the other.
How can I have my `.bashrc` file deal with the differences so I make my `.bashrc` file truly portable?

Similarly, how can I put a customized `.bashrc` file on a new machine immediately without having to satisfy all its dependencies first?  Having a non-functioning .bashrc file is tough as you can't even open a terminal window... (I always keep one open and test a new terminal window when editing my `.bashrc` file!  if you get 'stuck' this way you can use a plain text editor like gedit to change it)

Comment: IMHO this question is too broad.

Comment: Don't do like that. Keep a separate `.bashrc` on each system (which might `source` some common parts).

Comment: I'd love to see your list of approaches as a slightly-expanded blog post. Not the best fit for Q&A though.

Comment: @Basile - keep them in sync with frequent changes is a major pain.

Comment: No, you just have to use a version control system (like for any source code), e.g. [git](http://git-scm.com/), to manage these source files.

Comment: I should have been clearer perhaps - its a major pain for me *in my opinion*.  Yes I use git a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three approaches:

If a command depends on an enviromental variable such as the version of a program like bash or a variable like $TMUX you can use these in your `~.bashrc` file:

```
[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -ge 4 ] && shopt -s autocd
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=xterm-256color
```

If a `.bashrc` command depends on a file being present, e.g. a `~/.git-completion.bash` file:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi 

#(or)
[[ -s ~/.git-completion.bash ]] && source ~/.git-completion
```

If a command depends on a program being installed such as tmux:

```
if which tmux >/dev/null; then
  export TERM=xterm-256color
fi
```

Comment: All good approaches, although nothing specific to Linux vs OS X. You're missing an approach for the key difference between the two platforms: [GNU vs BSD coreutils](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104098/49971).